# Kafka offset - external storage vs consumer.committed(partition)

Tags: apache-kafka

I'me trying to use "Consumer external offset management" implementing ConsumerRebalanceListener.
I'm asking : Why does not use for onPartitionsAssigned calling `consumer.committed(partition)` to get the last committed offset instead of to read it from the same external storage? As I can see - kafka broker maintains itself this offset for each partition.
If we persisted last successfully reading message offset on external storage in @KafkaListener - the value of this offset will be exactly getting by `consumer.committed(partition)`.
Of course we have: `enable.auto.commit = false`